# How to send data via http request in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I was trying to make a django webapp and I can send data through the http request.
I want to send the id or number to be sent on the background not on the URL

my main goal was to send the data like the user object in django, so we can access the data in the html like the user object {{user}}

i tried to send with the request object but i didn't work

Comment: you need to use django forms

Comment: You can also send data using axios if you want to not refresh the page or clear current state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your requirement, you said the main goal is accessing the data in HTML like {{ user }}.

Since {{ user }} is a structure that Django uses for rendering template, I assume you are saying to render the data on an HTML page.

In that case, we could do something like this.

1. Get the use object
2. Pass it to a template by views.py
3. Rendering the user object in the template

Example:

In **views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def your_view(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=1)  # Replace it with your own query here
    return render(request, 'your_page.html', context={ 'user': user })  # Here pass the user object to template
```

In **template** - your_page.html

```
...
<h1>{{ user.id }}</h1><!-- Access user object's id. Replace id with the field that you look for -->
<p>{{ user.name }}</p><!-- Access user object's name. Replace name with the field that you look for -->
...
```

Comment: Hi @KirubelDemelash I appreciate it. A welcome comment for you to StackOverflow. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Cheers.